# Is there a CDI object from which I can access the CDI container?

Tags: java, containers, cdi

Is there a CDI object that can be used to grab the CDI container?

Comment: Answer depends on the problem you thought to solve with this information.

Comment: https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/CDI.html#current%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

org.jboss.weld.environment.se
Class WeldContainer

The WeldContainer can be used to access the CDI Container.

Comment: So you were discussing JBoss / Wildfly? Might want to add that as a tag.